# Should `io-streams` be allowed to be a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[io-streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams) is an I/O streaming [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) library. The name of course clashes with C++'s `iostream` and Stack Overflow complains that it shouldn't be a separate label.

Comment: Can we use `haskell-streams` or `haskell-io-streams`?

Comment: `haskell-streams` is probably too arbitrary, there are other streaming libraries (`pipes`,`conduit`). Does `haskell-io-streams` show up in the suggestions when `io-streams` is entered? That would be fine probably.

Comment: Based on [this trickery for io-stream](http://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=io-stream&newstyle=true&_=1468244668465) I assume `haskell-io-streams` should show up as [tag:boost-io-stream]  shows up as well. Just an extra note: Consider carefully if you want the tag to be plural or singular. You don't want to be hunted by a giant-S later ...

Comment: The library is called `io-streams` (with the `s`). What do you mean by "giant-S"?

Comment: [giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/158100)